# Bottom Bar Items not appearing in presentViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, presentviewcontroller

In my app, I dynamically load a set of images, and when a user taps on an image, it opens up a new ViewController (MediaPreview) that opens up a large preview of the image.

I create the MediaPreview controller as follows:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
mediaPreviewVC = (MediaPreviewViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MediaPreviewViewController"];
mediaPreviewVC.selectedImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",gestureRecognizer.view.tag];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mediaPreviewVC];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This creates a ViewController that looks like this:

[image]

However, the bottom navigation bar appears to be missing, which is outlined in my storyboard:

[image]

How can I ensure that the bottom navigation bar buttons appear in my view?

Comment: What is the status of `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` for `MediaPreviewVC`?

Comment: hide bottom bar on push is deselected

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the navigation controller out of whole cloth:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mediaPreviewVC];
```

`alloc-init` means "make me a completely fresh, separate, generic one". Thus, `navigationController` is *not* the navigation controller in your storyboard. It's a completely new and different navigation controller. Thus, what's in your storyboard is irrelevant.

If you wanted the navigation controller from your storyboard, you needed to instantiate the navigation controller *from the storyboard*. Or, if you're doing this intentionally, then the bottom bar won't be visible unless you explicitly make it visible, because by default it isn't (it's obvious how to [make it visible explicitly](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setToolbarHidden:animated:)).

But then in that case, if you meant to pull it out of the storyboard, then your *whole* code is probably wrong, because the one in the storyboard probably already has the correct root view controller as well.

Comment: thanks for your response.  if I created a new navigation controller, why is it that the title of the controller (Image Preview), which I've defined in the storyboard, is still visible in the app?  I don't know if I can create the navigation controller from the storyboard because I generate image thumbnails programmatically (they're not defined in my storyboard).  So I don't know how to add a segue to something that doesn't exist in the storyboard.

Comment: wow, as you mentioned, the bottom bar isn't visible unless explicitly stated.  after adding this:     [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO]; the problem was fixed.